# How to include background images in Keras multlabel image classification?

Tags: keras, multilabel-classification

I have been trying to train a multilabel classification model and want to include images that have no label to improve the training. I am using `flow_from_dataframe` to load the data and it sees the empty label list as a new class. I have also tried passing the class list into this function, in this case it completely ignores the images with no label. How can I train on images with no label in Keras?

Example of the dataframe I want to use:

```
0                        2022-04-06-16-15-18-209181.jpg            []
1                        2022-04-11-19-14-50-087726.jpg            []
2                        2022-04-06-16-15-11-507593.jpg            []
3                        2022-04-05-18-53-55-625837.jpg            [class1]
...                                                 ...                ...
3631                     2022-04-06-14-09-19-008147.jpg  [class1, class2]
3632                     2022-04-05-18-14-48-329041.jpg  [class1, class2]
```

Code:

```
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df,
    directory=data_dir + "/images",
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='labels',
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    subset='training',
    seed=42)
```

Comment: In supervised learning you need data with labels, you cannot just use unlabelled data and magically expect to improve the model. If you just need to load data without labels, you can make dummy labels in your pandas dataframe.

Comment: It is not unlabelled since I have confirmed those image do not contain instances of the 2 classes I am trying to learn. In a sense they are negative examples of the two classes, especially since some of them look very similar to `class1`. Wouldn't these examples improve the training of the model to correctly learn `class1` and '`class2`?